# Element r:require is not allowed here in intellij IDEA

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, plugins, taglib

I try to move my working project from GGTS to Intellij but I have this wierd problem. Intellij doesn't recognize some tags like `<r:require>`, `<r:script>`, `<markdown:renderHtml>`. I get the same error for all these tags. "`Element <tag-name> is not allowed here`"

Comment: Anyone, Anyone?